# Symfony2 Collection Form type - Not saving new records

Tags: forms, symfony, persistence, entity-relationship

I have implemented the 'collection' form type in my app, and it works great, including removing related records that are removed from the submitted data, however in order to save any newly added link record I have to manually loop through the links entities & set the owner as the entity being edited.  I'm sure it should do this automatically, so what have I missed?

You'll see a...

```
/*****************************************************************
 * This is the bit I've had to add to persist the new entries!!! *
 *****************************************************************
```

... where I've had to manually link the entities in the AppController file.

## The files

### App Entity

```
<?php

namespace ...\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * App
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class App
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...

    /**
     * @var AppAppStoreData[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * We use orphan removal here to remove the link data when deleting an app
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppAppStoreData", mappedBy="app", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
    private $appAppStoreData;

    // ...

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection|AppAppStoreData[]
     */
    public function getAppAppStoreData()
    {
        return $this->appAppStoreData;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection|AppAppStoreData[] $appAppStoreData
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAppAppStoreData( $appAppStoreData )
    {
        $this->appAppStoreData = $appAppStoreData;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

### AppStore Entity

```
<?php

namespace ...\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * AppStore
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class AppStore
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    // ...

    /**
     * @var AppAppStoreData[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * We use orphan removal here to remove the link data when deleting an app
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppAppStoreData", mappedBy="appStore", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
    private $appAppStoreData;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    // ...

    /**
     * @return AppAppStoreData[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getAppAppStoreData()
    {
        return $this->appAppStoreData;
    }

    /**
     * @param AppAppStoreData[]|ArrayCollection $appAppStoreData
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAppAppStoreData( $appAppStoreData )
    {
        $this->appAppStoreData = $appAppStoreData;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

### AppAppStoreData Entity

```
<?php

namespace ...\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * AppAppStoreData
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class AppAppStoreData
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var App
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App", inversedBy="appAppStoreData")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="app_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $app;

    /**
     * @var AppStore
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppStore", inversedBy="appAppStoreData")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="app_store_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $appStore;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="app_store_uri", type="string", length=1083)
     */
    private $appUri;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set app
     *
     * @param App $app
     *
     * @return AppAppStoreData
     */
    public function setApp(App $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get app
     *
     * @return App
     */
    public function getApp()
    {
        return $this->app;
    }

    /**
     * Set appStore
     *
     * @param AppStore $appStore
     *
     * @return AppAppStoreData
     */
    public function setAppStore(AppStore $appStore)
    {
        $this->appStore = $appStore;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get appStore
     *
     * @return AppStore
     */
    public function getAppStore()
    {
        return $this->appStore;
    }

    /**
     * Set appStoreLink
     *
     * @param string $appUri
     *
     * @return AppAppStoreData
     */
    public function setAppUri( $appUri)
    {
        $this->appUri = $appUri;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get appStoreLink
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAppUri()
    {
        return $this->appUri;
    }
}
```

### AppType Form

```
<?php

namespace ...\Form\Type;


use ...\Entity\App;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class AppType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Builds the App admin edit form
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder
            // ...
            ->add( 'appAppStoreData', 'collection', [
                'type'              => new ,
                'label'             => 'App Store Links',
                'allow_add'         => true,
                'allow_delete'      => true,
                'prototype'         => true,
                'widget_add_btn'    => array( 'label' => "Add App Store Details" ),
                'widget_remove_btn' => array( 'label' => "Remove App Store Details" ),
                'show_legend'       => false, // dont show another legend of subform
                'options'           => array( // options for collection fields
                    'label_render'                   => false,
                    'widget_addon_prepend'           => array(
                        'text' => '@',
                    ),
                    'horizontal_input_wrapper_class' => "col-lg-8",
                ),
            ] );
    }

    /**
     * Sets the Entity data class
     *
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions( OptionsResolverInterface $resolver )
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => '...\Entity\App',
            )
        );
    }


    /**
     * Returns the name of this type.
     *
     * @return string The name of this type
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app';
    }
}
```

### AppAppStoreDataFieldsType

```
<?php

namespace ...\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class AppAppStoreDataFieldsType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder
            ->add( 'appStore', 'entity', [
                'class'    => '...Bundle:AppStore',
                'property' => 'name',
                'label'    => 'App Store'
            ] )
            ->add( 'appUri', 'url', [
                'label' => 'App URI'
            ] );
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions( OptionsResolverInterface $resolver )
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults( array(
            'data_class' => '...\Entity\AppAppStoreData'
        ) );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_store_data_fields';
    }
}
```

### App Controller

```
<?php

namespace ...\Controller;

use ...\Entity\UploadableInterface;
use ...\Exception\RecordNotFoundException;
use ...\Exception\RedirectException;
use ...\Entity\App;
use ...\Entity\AppRepository;
use ...\Entity\ClientRepository;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class AppController extends ClientAssetController
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param null    $id
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function editAction( Request $request, $id = null )
    {
        $app = @$this->getAppRepository()->find( $id );

        // ...

        $form = $this->createForm( 'app', $app )
                     ->add( 'save', 'submit', [ 'label' => 'Save' ] );

        $form->handleRequest( $request );

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist( $app );


            /*****************************************************************
             * This is the bit I've had to add to persist the new entries!!! *
             *****************************************************************
             /
            foreach ($app->getAppAppStoreData() as $appAppStoreDatum) {
                $appAppStoreDatum->setApp( $app );
            }


            $em->flush();

            // ... Redirect
        }

        // ... Render
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize the collection of `appAppStoreData`:

```
...

public function __construct()
{
    $this->appAppStoreData = new ArrayCollection();
}
```